# Android screen size and resolution

Tags: android, xml, drawable, resolution, screen-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android screen size resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864497/android-screen-size-resolution)

My app works perfectly in resolution 480x800. If I keep the 480x800 resolution but change the screen size to for example 2.7 inches, 3.7 inches or 5.4 inches it still is perfect. But when I change the resolution to for example 640x1066 all the ImageButtons is too small and in the wrong place in all screen sizes... I have created ImageButtons in all four folders(drawable-l, m, h, xh) but still the buttons is not in the correct size..

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="433dp"
    android:background="@drawable/imagebutton1" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="188dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="436dp"
    android:background="@drawable/imagebutton2" />
```

NOTE: My problem is not when I change screen size, but when I change screen resolution.

Comment: Next time please use the "edit" link in the lower left corner of your question to add this new information to your original question: [Android screen size resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864497/android-screen-size-resolution). (I already did this for you.) But it is unnecessary and [forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) to create a "new" question that is the same as an old one.